# Highcharts Grouped Column with Time Series

Tags: highcharts

I know how to make the regular columns in highcharts that are grouped and I know how to make a time series for a line chart OR columns (they have examples for these), but what I can't seem to figure out is how to create a time series for grouped columns. The closest I can get is overlapping columns.

I'm looking for something like this (**made in paint**): 
[image: grouped column time series chart](https://i467.photobucket.com/albums/rr40/hosoi_dan/grouped_column_time_series_zpsbd2afb7d.jpg)

Here's what my code looks like:
`

```
var data =
[
    /* Apr 2013 */
    {name:"T1",x:1364774400000, y:13918927, color:"red"},
    {name:"T1",x:1364774400000, y:10920462, color:"green"},
    [1364860800000,18920462],
    [1364947200000,12971961],

    /* May 2013 */
    [1367366400000,18112671],
    [1367452800000,15072312]
];




$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        alignTicks: false,
            type: 'column'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },
    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
        data: data
    }]
});
```

`

And a jsfillde with the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/UH5wj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is general idea: http://jsfiddle.net/wFpey/

So split data into series according to name. Then create array of points, where each point is object or array (my example is array).

```
var series = [ {
    name: "T1",
    data: [
        [1364774400000, 13918927], [1364974400000, 13918927]
    ],
    color: "red"
}, {
    name: "T2",
    data: [
        [1364774400000,10920462], [1364974400000, 13918927]
    ],
    color: "green"
}, {
    name: "T3",
    data: [
        [1364774400000, 12312312], [1364974400000, 13918927]
    ],
    color: "blue"
}, {
    name: "T4",
    data: [
        [1364774400000, 12311111], [1364974400000, 13918927]
    ],
    color: "yellow"
}, {
    name: "T5",
    data: [
        [1364774400000, 11233345], [1364974400000, 13918927]
    ],
    color: "gray"
}, {
    name: "T6",
    data: [
        [1364774400000, 14322311]
    ],
    color: "black"
}];
```

Comment: I think this is EXACTLY what I wanted. I thought it would just be something with how the data is organized, but wasn't sure how and didn't see any documentation that suggested the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how your data is coming in, I can only get you so far, but take a look at this. The two keys here are the spacing between series points, taken care of in the plotOptions section, and defining categories on the xAxis to be grouped in. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UH5wj/1/)

```
$(function() {

var data =
[
/* Apr 2013 */
{name:"T1",x:1364774400000, y:13918927, color:"red"},
{name:"T1",x:1364774400000, y:10920462, color:"green"},
[1364860800000,18920462],
[1364947200000,12971961],
/* May 2013 */
[1367366400000,18112671],
[1367452800000,15072312]
];
    /*$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-      v.json&callback=?', function(data) {*/

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            alignTicks: false,
            type: 'column'
        },

        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0, 
            shadow: false
            }
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
            data: data
        }],
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apr 2013', 'May 2013'] ///needs to be specific to your data, this is just an idea not knowing your data
        },
    });
//});
});
```

EDIT: saw your data up top after, needs some tweaking a bit, but I hope you get the idea

Comment: The data format hasn't been decided. I will format it so that it works the easiest in the Highchart code.

The problem isn't the spacing, as you have changed, but to have multiple columns for a specific date and in the chart to have all columns for a specific date side by side and have spaces between the groups.

If you look at the jsfiddle, the green and the red are overlapping because they have the same date.

Comment: OK, I can see more what you are going for. I still believe the key lies within setting up categories within your data (the padding will be easy once that's established). I'll think on it more, but if you get to it first, categories are where I'd focus my energy

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. That's why I was testing changing each piece of data in the series to an object with a name. But I don't think highcharts/highstock has this functionality out of the box.